# Handling multiple projects within Redmine / SVN (single repo)

Tags: project-management, redmine, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

Current setup is VSS with a single master project, nested under this single project are numerous other projects (typically with other nested projects within).

I'm trying to move to SVN (VisualSVN) and include Redmine (installed via Bitnami stack), but I'm a little confused on how best to replicate the current setup.

Right now, I have a single master repo with a bunch of sub-directories for projects and some sub-sub-directories for projects within projects (all related to each other).

My issue is that in Redmine, it asks for my repo URL.  I tried using HTTPS but continually get errors (I'm guessing it is something to do with SSL cert not being accepted).  I tried searching / resolving the issue but to no avail.  I was able to get around this by using "file:///" and mapping the repo that way.  The problem with this "solution" is that when I create a project / sub-project in Redmine and try to add the repo (using file:///), I get the root of the repo...all of my projects / sub-projects within the repo are present.

Maybe it is my lack of understanding of SVN / Redmine but is it possible to only show a sub-directory within a repo, rather than the entire repo?  I would prefer not to have 100+ repos for all the projects when most of the projects are similar in nature.  When I look at the repo within repo browser, I can see the nested project folders but I don't understand (if it's even possible) how to point my "repo" for a particular project to that sub-directory and not the root of the repo.

I tried searching for someone with a similar scenarios / questions but to no avail.  Hopefully my question makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

With SVN, any subfolder is a repository in its own right.

For example:

```
+ svnroot
|
+-+ Proj 1
| |
| +-+ Proj 1.1
etc.
```

You can reference each sub-project by just setting the SVN root in Redmine to that particular folder. In my example, to access `Proj 1.1`, that would be `svn://SERVER/svnroot/Prod 1/Prod 1.1/`.

A course I took in school used this feature to allow the instructor to have a single SVN repository for all the students but each student still only had access to their own "sub-repository".

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for the suggestion.  I ended up dropping the HTTPS requirement and I was able to browse sub-directories of repositories (where as when using file:///, I could never browse to a repo sub-directory).

Comment: I use this approach, giving each project a subversion folder. But there are problems, for example: one project was renamed a while ago. Using Trac and a single repo I could see where then new folder originate from, but not so using Redmine. If I link to a changeset before the rename I get the error message that this reivision is not available in the repository.